# elasticsearch @ debian6 started by /etc/init.d max_file_descriptors

Tags: debian, init.d, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch @ debian6 by [this tutorial](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2010/07/02/setting-up-elasticsearch-on-debian.html).
I have set up my system max open files directives so i have these values:

```
# su
# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
70000

# ulimit -Hn
64000

# ulimit -Sn
32000
```

When i check elasticsearch max_file_descriptors by:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes?process=true&pretty=true'
```

**i'll get 1024**.

When i restart it by root user, it has "max_file_descriptors" : 64000 now.

Whats wrong with that init.d autostart?
When i check htop, elastic autostarted by init.d with that 1024 descriptors is runnig under root user too.

**I have set max files open by 2 confs:**

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf
...
fs.file-max = 70000

cat /etc/security/limits.conf
...
*   soft    nofile  32000
*   hard    nofile  64000

root    soft    nofile  32000
root    hard    nofile  64000
```

Comment: How did you increase the open file limit?

Comment: I updated my question by these informations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The settings in `/etc/security/limits.conf` usually get applied by the `pam_limits` [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM) module. Services started by `init` don't run under a PAM session however, and so these settings are not applied. The only reliable way I've found to set this is to run `ulimit` from the initscript itself. Edit the ElasticSearch initscript and add something like this near the top:

```
ulimit -n 64000
```

I'm not sure that you want to set `sys.file-max` BTW; on my system it defaults to 779149, and so you may be decreasing it by an order of magnitude.